# Can we synonymize sleep and suspend?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can we synonymize [sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sleep) and [suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/suspend)?

Sleep tag excerpt:

> A power-saving state, basically same thing as "Standby mode", that allows a computer to quickly resume full-power operation (typically within several seconds) when you want to start working again.

Suspend tag excerpt:

> Questions related to Suspend Mode, which is a special low-power mode often used on laptops that preserves the contents of RAM while using less power than normal.

**BTW, both tags need some review as they are question that don't fit within the description in the excerpt.**

Comment: Maybe you should propose the synonym in the tag so the rest of us can vote on it?

Comment: I don't have enough points on this tag.

Comment: @JorgeCastro You are the one with a score of 10 in the tag :P

Comment: I don't have enough points in suspend!

Comment: @JorgeCastro Oh I thought you needed 5 in sleep...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The famous dinosaur (aka Jokerdino), just make this status complete.

Answer (score 4):

In spite of what the tag wiki says, "suspend" can properly refer to "suspend to RAM" (sleep, standby), or "suspend to disk" (hibernation).

With that said, **people seem to use "suspend" to mean "sleep," and not to mean "hibernate."** So, it would be okay to make these synonyms so long as:

- [suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/suspend) can have a separate tag wiki (which I believe is possible, unless the tags are actually *merged*)
- [suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/suspend)'s tag wiki is edited to mention that [hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hibernate) should be used instead, for questions about "suspend to disk."

Comment: I often forget this myself.